# Is it possible to identify where apps come from?

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, vanilla-android

I have a new tablet that I installed CM12.1 and Pico GApps on. Here is a picture of the app screen:

[image: CM12.1 App screen]

I'd like to understand where each app comes from (either AOSP, CM or GApps). Is this something I can deduce from the apps' location on the filesystem, or the apps themselves perhaps ?

I have tried to find the information on the relevant sites for AOSP, CM and OpenGApps but have so far drawn a blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Gathered additional content from the comments.

- CM will list the package name of the apps in Apps Info. Those with `com.cyanogenmod`, `org.cyanogenmod`, `cyanogen` and `com.cyngn` (thanks @Izzy !) are certainly Cyanogen-specific, those with `com.android` are *possibly* AOSP-based and those with `google` are from Google. Alternately, list package names via `adb shell pm list packages` and [find out the app name of a certain package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650765/get-application-name-label-via-adb-shell-or-terminal) (e.g. using `adb shell 'dumpsys | grep -A18 "Package \[org.cyanogenmod.audiofx\]"'`).
- For launcher entries that are parts of other apps, dragging them either to Apps Info or Uninstall will reveal what parent apps they belong to.
- Explore your Pico GAPPS zip package to see what it installs. The apps might not be in APK format (OpenGAPPS compresses them in tar packages) but the filenames are still recognizable. Every app not in the package is part of CM itself.

As for which CM apps are based off of AOSP... I'd say it's hard to *definitively* find out without digging into CM sources.

Comment: The only app I cannot identify ysing the above messages is the one called *"Google Settings"*. I guess it is part of `com.google.android.gms` but that's what it is - a guess!

Answer (score 2):

Cyanogenmod 12.1 comes with built-in (official CM) apps  which contains the following apps (`com.cyanogen.*`):

- File manager (CM version)
- Theme Store (CM version)
- AudioFX (CM version)
- Gallery (CM version)

There is available for CM12.1 builds an app package called "[`C-Apps Package`](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/introducing-the-cyanogen-apps-package)" which (ships by default with CyanogenOS and) contains the following apps (`com.cyngn.*`):

- Theme Chooser with per-app theming (Cyanogen OS version)
- Theme Store (Cyanogen OS version)
- AudioFX (Cyanogen OS version)
- Cyanogen Accounts
- Gallery (Cyanogen OS version)
- Dialer with TrueCaller integration
- Email powered by Boxer

> This package will allow you to take your existing devices running CM 12.1, and make them more like the Cyanogen OS experience. […] C-Apps is being offered as an optional download and will not be preinstalled on CyanogenMod releases.

[`GApps Pico`](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Pico-Package) contains the following apps:

- Google system base
- Google Play Store
- Google Calendar Sync
- Dialer Framework
- Google Package Installer (replaces stock/AOSP Package Installer)
- Google Play services

The rest apps are from the core Android system.

Comment: I don't have the C-Apps but I do have *AudioFX* (`org.cyanogenmod.audiofx`) and *Themes* (`org.cyanogenmod.theme.chooser`), plus the AOSP *Gallery* (`com.android.gallery3d`). I wonder if the CM versions of AudioFX and Themes are the same as the C-Apps ones... (but I'm going a bit O.T there)

Comment: From what I can gather, CM (12.1) provides *AudioFX* (`org.cyanogenmod.audiofx`), *File Manager* (`com.cyanogenmod.filemanager`) and *Themes* (`org.cyanogenmod.theme.chooser`). There is no *Theme Store* - the chooser direects the user to *Google Play* or the *CM Wiki*.

Comment: @starfry and Bálint: I've integrated parts of your comments with the answer, and also made clear how to tell the C-Apps from CMod and COS apart (package prefixes). Comments are cleaned up now (this last one will self-destruct in a few minutes).

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers :) @andyyan answer explains *how* to discover the information.

Comment: No problem, glad to help you. :)